# How to initialize two attributes of type list with the same list?

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Bins: 
   
    def __init__(self, id:str, initial_list:list):
        self.id_ = id
        self.capacities = initial_list 
        self.remaining_capacities = initial_list
        
example = Bins("t1",[0,0,1])
example.capacities[1] = 1
print(example.remaining_capacities) # gives [0, 1, 1]
```

As shown, the problem with this approach is that I cannot modify the attributes independently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: `self.remaining_capacities = initial_list[:]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght what's the difference between this approach and the one given by Moosa in his answer?

Comment: @JoffreyL. both are same, see the duplicate link.

Comment: @JoffreyL., there's no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `list.copy()` to make a deep copy.

```
    def __init__(self, id:str, initial_list:list):
        self.id_ = id
        self.capacities = initial_list.copy()
        self.remaining_capacities = initial_list.copy()
```

Comment: what's the difference between this approach and the one given by Olvin in his comment below my question?